# Measure to create a constant line within two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to make a horisontal line with a constant value that starts and ends at a projects start and finish dates respectively.

Tables are as follows:

DateTable

```
Date           
28/09/2018      
29/09/2018     
30/09/2018      
01/10/2018      
02/10/2018
```

ProjectTable

```
Project     Start         Finish
X-100       28/09/2018    30/09/2018
```

I've tried doing

```
Measure = CALCULATE(1; FILTER(DateTable; DateTable[Date] >= FIRSTDATE(ProjectTable[Start]) && DateTable[Date] <= FIRSTDATE(ProjectTable[Finish)))
```

But I can't get the line to be within the Start and Finish from ProjectTable. It will just expand the entire range of dates available in the DateTable.

Answer (score 2):

The genaral rule is that blank values will not show in your line chart.

To illustrate this, I expanded your ProjectTable with two more projects and a [Value] column. So it now looks like this.

[image]

Then I created the following maesure:

```
Measure =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable[Date] )
        >= LOOKUPVALUE (
            'ProjectTable'[Start],
            ProjectTable[Project], SELECTEDVALUE ( ProjectTable[Project] )
        )
        && SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable[Date] )
            <= LOOKUPVALUE (
                'ProjectTable'[Finish],
                ProjectTable[Project], SELECTEDVALUE ( ProjectTable[Project] )
            ),
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        'ProjectTable'[Value],
        ProjectTable[Project], SELECTEDVALUE ( ProjectTable[Project] )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Because there is no relation between the DateTable and the ProjectTable, I had to use the LOOKUPVALUE function to get the values for [Start], [Finish] and [Value]. The resulting Linechart visual looks like this:

[image]